# Why does $E\left(y_{i t}\right)=a^{\prime}\left(\theta_{i t}\right)$? in the context of assuming some GEE marginal density?

Tags: mean, marginal-distribution, exponential-family, generalized-estimating-equations

In generalized estimating equations we have a glm-response variable.

> To establish notation, we let $Y_{i}=\left(y_{i 1}, \ldots, y_{i n_{i}}\right)^{\text {T }}$ be the $n_{i} \times 1$ vector of outcome values and $X_{i}=\left(x_{i 1}, \ldots, x_{i n_{i}}\right)^{\mathrm{T}}$ be the $n_{i} \times p$ matrix of covariate values for the $i$th subject $(i=1, \ldots, K)$. We assume that the marginal density of $y_{i t}$ is
> $$
> f\left(y_{i t}\right)=\exp \left[\left\{y_{i t} \theta_{i t}-a\left(\theta_{i t}\right)+b\left(y_{i t}\right)\right\} \phi\right],
> $$
> where $\theta_{i t}=h\left(\eta_{i t}\right), \eta_{i t}=x_{i t} \beta$. By this formulation, the first two moments of $y_{i t}$ are given by
> $$
> E\left(y_{i t}\right)=a^{\prime}\left(\theta_{i t}\right), \quad \operatorname{var}\left(y_{i t}\right)=a^{\prime \prime}\left(\theta_{i t}\right) / \phi
> $$

I know we integrate over all possible $y_{it}$ of the function $f(y_{it})y_{it}$ to find $E[y_{it}]$

I don't understand how the mean is only related to the derivative of $a(\theta_{it})$

---

Citation: KUNG-YEE LIANG, SCOTT L. ZEGER, Longitudinal data analysis using generalized linear models, Biometrika, Volume 73, Issue 1, April 1986, Pages 13–22, https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/73.1.13

Comment: "Your session has timed out. Please go back to the article page and click the PDF link again." - after clicking the hyperlink.

Comment: Longitudinal data analysis using generalized linear models
BY KUNG-YEE LIANG AND SCOTT L. ZEGER
Department of Biostatistics, Johns Hopkins University, Baltimore, Maryland 21205,
U.S.A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's what the exponential family model does: it makes the parameters directly model the mean.

The log partition function for an observation is
$$\log f= (y\theta-a(\theta)+b(y))/\phi$$
Differentiate with respect to $\theta$ to get
$$(y - a'(\theta))/\phi.$$
Taking expectations
$$E[Y]-a'(\theta)=0$$

Comment: How do you know the log-partition function is $f$?

Comment: How do you know the log-partition function is $f$? What's the base measure, and sufficient statistic @Thomas Lumley